# To unbind routing keys from rabbitmq using declarables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How to unbind routing keys from already created queue using declarables. I am using below code to declare queues and bind the routing keys

```
 @Bean
public Declarables ds() {
Declarables declarables = new Declarables();
declarables.getDeclarables().add(topicExchange());
declarables.getDeclarables().add(new Queue("queueName", false);
for (String chain : chainNames)
    declarables.getDeclarables().add(new Binding("queueName", Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE,
                                "XYZ", "routing key pattern", null));
return declarables;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for unbinding via `Declarables`; you can do it manually with

```java
rabbitAdmin.removeBinding(...);
```

But you should not do that in a `@Bean` definition.

Comment: Corrected - the `RabbitAdmin` has a `removeBinding` method - no need to drop to the low-level API.